# MFC CListCtrl Max Column count limit?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have googled for this but can't seem to find if there is a maximum column limitation to MFC's CListCtrl i.e number of columns for the list. Wondering if there is one, as I'm having a problem displaying more than X amount of columns & it just crashes when I try to display it. I'm using virtual list by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely at this point you know what the number `X` is?

Comment: P.S. If there is a limit, it will be far beyond what any reasonable program would create. I'd start with the assumption that there's a bug in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Just as I was going to post my code I realised what was wrong, my code, in a section of code I didn't think to look at. Working as intended now. Cheers